# Prevent vim from yanking whole lines

Tags: regex

The command **:/point a/,/point b/y** in vim allows me to yank lines 2 to 4 in the following example. However, I want to select only the text between point a and point b and not the complete lines.

*--- start example ---

copy from **point a** 

to 

**point b**

--- end example ---*

I know this can be achieved using Visual mode, or using markers. However, I want to know how can I do this using search patterns like the search command mentioned above. The yanked text I am looking for is this one:

***point a 

to 

point b***

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

What you might be after is a positive lookbehind+lookahead.

`(?<=group)pattern` - **Positive lookbehind** - Matches as single instance of a pattern which proceeds the specified group but does not include the group in the match.

`pattern(?=group)` - **Positive lookahead** - Matches a single instance of a pattern which is followed by the specified group but does NOT include the group in the match.

**Example:**

```
(?<=pointa)pattern(?=pointb)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

**Sample text**

```
copy from point a
to  
point b
```

**Sequence of commands**

```
// '(\_s\|.\)*' Matches line breaks or any character 0 or more times.
/point a\(\_s\|.\)*point b
// (press enter)
// Select the matched result in visual mode.
gn
// Now yank it. 
y 
// Put it somewhere else.
p 
// You get :
// point a
// to
// point b
```

I think yank can only make that kind of selection in visual mode and it will copy whole lines involving the movement in other cases.